# Encode txt file with caesar cipher java

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to encode a txt file in java with caesar cipher.I decide the shift by myself and I have written the code below but I get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
```

Can someone help me fix it? Thank you!

```
public class zevenedesim {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("words.txt"));
        String teksti = input.nextLine();
        zevenedesim(teksti, output);
    }

    public static void zevenedesim(String text, PrintStream output) {
        int i = 0;
        String s;
        Scanner data = new Scanner(text);
        if (data.hasNext()) {
            s = data.next();
            if (s.charAt(i) >= 97 && s.charAt(i) <= 120) {
                int x = s.charAt(i) - 97;
                x = (x + 2) % 26;
                if (x < 0)
                    x += 26;
                // = (char) (x + 32);
            }
            output.print(" " + data.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your file is empty.

Comment: You are reading and writing to the same file.

Comment: I fixed it but there's something wrong cause if I write "Hello Java" the output will be " Java"

Answer (score 0):

You create your output `PrintWriter` on the same file you take your input from. Initializing a `PrintWriter` on an existing file will remove its content, as stated by [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream-java.io.File-):

> If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero size.

Just use different files for input and output, and you should be fine:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("encoded_words.txt"));
```

Comment: Yeah I tried it but there's something wrong cause if I write "Hello Java" the output will be " Java"

Comment: @Malvina that's a different issue - you're calling `next()` twice each iteration of the loop, and not doing anything with the characters you encode...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold. Firstly, you open the same file for reading and writing simultaneously. When you open a file for writing, the file is cleared, so when you start reading, Scanner throws a `NoSuchElementException` because there is nothing there. To fix that problem, save your output to a different file.

Secondly, your read/write logic is all wrong. You read a word with `data.next()`, run each character through the Caesar cipher but don't store the result anywhere, then read another word with `output.print(" " + data.next());` and write that second word to the output completely un-encoded, completely discarding the first word. That's why you are reading "Hello Java" and writing just " Java" with no encoding. Rather than trying to fix that, I just rewrote the whole thing, going line by line instead of word by word.

Here is how I would implement the program, with both errors fixed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class zevenedesim {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int shift = 2;
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt")); 
                PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("encoded_words.txt"))) {
            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                output.println(caesar(input.nextLine(), shift));
            }
        }
    }

    public static String caesar(String text, int shift) {
        shift %= 26;
        if (shift == 0) return text;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            int c = text.charAt(i);

            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                c += shift;
                if (c > 'Z') c -= 26;
            } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                c += shift;
                if (c > 'z') c -= 26;
            }

            sb.append((char) c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```